# Изменение целой страницы в табах

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Здравсвуйте. 
Возможно ли на JS , при переключении табов , подгружать совсем другую страницу? 
Например: Tab1 в нем лежит page-1.html . Переключаю таб -> Tab2 в нем уже лежит page-2.html 
Либо может есть альтернативный способ? 
Спасибо за Ваши идеи!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, более того, часто используется в том или ином виде.
Фактически, реализация вашего вопроса есть в примерах на http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax

Тоже самое можно сделать и без jquery, на чистом js с использованием XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: Я попытался использовать .load()

Comment: Однако срабатывает ровно один раз 
При переключении табов 
т.е один раз переключил - прогрузило ,
затем прошел по остальным 
пытаюсь вернуться, а загрузки уже нет.
использовал так $(".container").load("/page.html .wrapper");

Comment: Вероятнее всего ваша проблема в кешировании ответа. Существует множество вариантов борьбы, самый простой можно попробовать делать это так: var d = new Date(); $(".container").load("/page.html?"+d.getTime()); Либо использовать флаг { cache: false }